# How can I change the font for all items in Vuetify from Roboto to another

Tags: vue.js, fonts, vuetify.js

**How can I change the font for all items in Vuetify from Roboto to another.**

I use Vuetify, there is a default Roboto font. I want to change it to another. Changing the font in the variables.scss file does not help, because each class has a specific Roboto font.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Oxygen:300,400,700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Comfortaa&display=swap');

$body-font-family: 'Oxygen';
$title-font: 'Comfortaa';
$heading-font-family: 'Oxygen';
```

However, when I use classes like this:

`class = "text-md-h6 text-lg-h6 .text-xl-caption"`

the Roboto font is still used.

```
@media (min-width: 1024px)
<style>
.v-application .text-xl-caption {
    font-size: 0.75rem !important;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.25rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.0333333333em !important;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif !important;
}
```

What do I need to do to change the font in all places?

Answer (score 4):

This should work by setting the font variables in variables.scss file as [documented here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#sass-variables). A couple things to check if it doesn't work:

- The file should be in an expected folder src/[sass, scss or styles]. [Docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#vue-cli-install).
- Vuetify Loader should be installed along with sass and sass-loader as dev dependencies
- Variables file [only contains variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#importing-in-variable-files), not imports. Fonts could be declared/imported in main or elsewhere.

Comment: Can you show me part of the generated code in the `class text-md-h1`? That in result there were custom fonts. As well as part of the file in the `variable.scss`. I've already tried to do that. **'not imports'** this is a misconception, there is an import, there is no import in the vail where their classes are written, without import a variable it is impossible to overwrite variables

Comment: Yes, "text-md-h1" and other classes generate the correct custom font for me, accomplished solely by setting $body-font-family. I suspect there is something wrong with your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bad practice to use `!important` for most of the cases and unfortunately because those `font-family` styles also have `!important` CSS will only use the style with a more specific selector so You also have to use `!important`. You can try something like `.v-application .v-application--wrap *` with `!important`. so it will be like :

```
.v-application .v-application--wrap * {
font-family: $body-font-family !important;
}
```

and if you have different styles for different classes , you can just put all of them inside a `.v-application .v-application--wrap { }` and sass will process them for you. **but also note that other vuetify classes might use more specific selectors , so in those cases you have to use more specific selectors for those specific cases.**

Comment: Are you a vuetify expert or just giving advice at random? I showed what structure is on the html page after compiling the project on vue + vuetify. That's not what I use `!important` this system automatically creates.

Comment: I am not giving advice at random , and I know what's the problem and I have dealt with it alot. I understand that vuetify generates those styles and you just have to override them to whatever you want them to be . the answer I gave was what I found the easiest way to deal with it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not what I'm interested in.  I know how to reinstall certain styles.  But this is also not a very good option.  I want to find a way to change once and then everything worked, the same situation with adjusting the font size.